# What does $\mathbb{R} / 4\pi \mathbb{Z} ≅ S^1$ mean?

Tags: general-topology

In a paper I have encountered

> The solid angle is the magnetostatic potential normalised to be $4\pi$ cyclic, i.e it takes the values in $\mathbb{R} / 4\pi \mathbb{Z} ≅ S^1$.

What does this mean? It seems to describe a quotient space related somehow (≅) to the unit circle?

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of the question cited as the reason for closure, which has nothing to do with angles.